# Jbuilder: json.variable instead of json.name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I'm using jbuiler to generate api, when I go generate a value, I do:

```
json.name type.name
```

I'd like to use the value type.name, for example, to generate the name of the value, this way I could generate an array with the name of my value:

```
json.type.name do
  json.array categories
end
```

How can I use a variable instead a static string for the value of my parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
json.set! type.name do
  json.array categories
end
```